# Performant intersection algorithm for Bounding Box with a Line Segment emanating from its center point

Tags: performance, algorithm, graphics, geometry, 2d

There are many close, helpful answers to similar questions listed on stackoverflow, however i have not found any yet that match my particular case.

I need a performance efficient algorithm to calculate the intersection of a Bounding Box with a Line Segment emanating from its center point. Each Bounding Box may have multiple Line Segment emanations.

By the definition of my problem, each Line Segment will intersect one (and except for 4 points ONLY ONE) of the Bounding Box Edge segments.

Here is an illustration.

[image: Four Bounding Boxes connected with Line Segments emanating from center points]

I want to quickly and computationally "cheaply" compute:

1. Which Bounding Box Edge the Line Segment intersects?
2. What is the point at which the Edge and the Line Segment intersects?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are given the line's start and end point and the bounding box's size? What algorithm do you currently use and how is it too slow?

Comment: why dont you start calculating the intersection point of two lines, which you have learned in school.

Answer (score 0):

Let C be the center of the bounding box and P the other endpoint of the segment. Let V = (Vx, Vy) = P - C be the vector pointing from C to P.

Let the bounding box have height = 2 * H and width = 2 * W. W and H are half of the normal height and width, which will make the computations below simpler.

Here is the idea: Consider the case where V is in the first quadrant, so Vx > 0 and Vy > 0. The segment then intersects the top side or right side. We can tell the which one by comparing the slope of V and the slope of the segment from the center of the box to the top right corner. If the slope is larger, then it intersects the top and otherwise it intersects the side.

So, if V is in the first quadrant, and if Vy / Vx > H / W the segment intersects the top. If Vy / Vx < H / W, it intersects the side. If they are equal, it intersects the corner.

Once you know which side it intersects, you can use similar triangles to figure out the point of intersection. If it intersects the top at the point I = (Ix, H), then Vx / Vy = Ix / H or Ix = H * Vx / Vy. If it intersects the side at the point I = (W, Iy) then Vy / Vx = Iy / W or Iy = W * Vy / Vx.

The same methods will work in the other quadrants; you just need to keep track of the signs of Vx and Vy. You can make your life a bit easier by asserting that the return value satisfies sign(Ix) == sign(Vx) and sign(Iy) == sign(Vy).

Note also that, if you are careful with signs, you can avoid division: Vy / Vx > H / W is equivalent to Vy * W > Vx * H, assuming that Vx > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a square box centered on (0,0), with sides of length 2.
Suppose you have a vector (dx,dy) radiating from the center of the box.
Then this calculates (xp,yp) the point where the ray intersects an edge.

It executes two `fabs`, two comparisons, one division, and two assignments.
Then you just have to translate and scale it to your particular squares.

```
if (fabs(dx) > fabs(dy)){
  if (dx > 0){
    xp = 1;     // right side
    yp = dy/dx;
  } else {
    xp = -1;     // left side
    yp = -dy/dx
  }
} else {
  if (dy > 0){
    yp = 1;     // top side
    xp = dx/dy;
  } else {
    yp = -1;     // bottom side
    xp = -dx/dy
  }
}
```

Comment: ( missing a close parenthesis on your first line of code )